# Graylog- How to check the flow of messages between different services in logs in Graylog?

Tags: graylog, graylog2, graylog3

Graylog newbie here. I was wondering how I could check the flow of messages between dependent services in logs in Graylog. I'll give a small instance to make my self clear.
Let's there 4 services A,B,C and D.
How do i find this or trace this flow in the Graylog

A->B->C->D->A->C(crash).

Any answer would be appreciated as I am struggling to find answers for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to tie these messages together, you need some sort of a key value. Some element that is present in all four log sources that lets you know they are related.

It could be a hostname, or an IP. Anything common between the four will do.

If you don’t have a key value, you will have to write a query that includes all four sources.

Something like “source:A OR B OR C OR D”. Then use timestamps to establish the sequence you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anything I could do to add the traceId from the message as the common attribute?

Comment: The traceID from which message? You can add a field and value to any message. However, knowing which messages go with that traceid would be challenging.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but that is exact;y what I am looking for, how do I trace an error occured in one of the services I am using?